# Can I "see" Java Standard Libraries Offline

Tags: java, oracle, bluej, standard-library

Well, I am using BlueJ. I know I can use them offline for sure. But would it be possible to see the Oracle documentation without Internet connection? Included Method summary and description. Something like this but offline

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

I know it is not of the cleverest of questions but I really need it. Hope for any suggestions.

P.S. There are the `CTRL` and `space` for suggestions(in Eclipse this is automatically done) but I look for the documentation.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/jdk8-doc-downloads-2133158.html perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the official documentation at oracle's download center.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/jdk8-doc-downloads-2133158.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you download a version of the documentation?
 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/java-se-7-doc-download-435117.html